# Object type 'ShortAnswer' not found in schema in Realm React Native

Tags: react-native, realm

My schema defination in file `realmDB.js` :

```
'use strict';
var Realm = require('realm');

class ShortAnswer extends Realm.Object{}
ShortAnswer.schema = {
  name: 'ShortAnswer',
  properties: {
  question: 'string',
  answer: 'string'
 }
};
export default new Realm({schema: [ShortAnswer]});
```

In my `short_answer.js` file,
I include the `realmDB` by using `import realm from './realmDB';`.

Here,

```
realm.write(() => {
  realm.create('ShortAnswer',{
    question: this.state.short_question,
    answer: this.state.short_answer
  });
});
```

I am new in realm and react native.
The input for the question and answer is taken from two respective `TextInput`. But when i give input and press the save button to save question and answer into the database, the error `Object type 'ShortAnswer' not found in schema.` occurs. What can be done to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar error message and problem. Turns out I need to do a better job of reading the realm documentation. In my case I had multiple Realms, on for Contacts and another for Auth data. The Auth data realm was created more recently and was overwriting the Contacts realm. To solve this problem I needed to add a path to the realm creation like so:

```
export default new Realm({path: 'somePath.realm', schema: [ShortAnswer]});
```

Afterwards everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

This should work. The only thing I see different from mine is that you are inheriting from `Realm.Object`. Have you tried just doing this?

`class ShortAnswer {}`

Comment: It does not work either. Will you provides some sort of your sample to help me ? I want to know how you implement like this.

Comment: What version of Realm are you using?

Comment: I just created a new RN project, added realm, and copy/pasted your code in and it seems to work. Does this work for you?

Comment: Having the same issue, on Realm 0.14.3, react-native 0.38.0 running multiple realms, other realms seem to work fine. My code worded fine previously and broke after a couple of weeks not touching that part of the code base.